Cleanup for Dockerfile Staged Build
For Dockerfile while using multi staged builds e.g.
FROM some-build-env as build
RUN run-sum-build


FROM prod-env
COPY --from=build /source/dist /dist

does it really make any sense to make any cleanup stuff for intermediate stages like
RUN apk remove -y git make

As I understand intermediate stages aren't included it self into a resulting image so should one really care the "garbage" it has
Thx

Docker is based on an overlay filesystem: each modification (RUN) results in a new layer which stores added/changed files or the information about the removed ones.
In other words the RUN apk remove -y git make will use additional disk space for the new layer, leaving intact the previous ones.
For that reason it does not have any sense.
Here you can find more about the Overlay filesystem.
